# How to execute batch file from Java code?

Tags: batch-file

im trying to invoke a batch file from java code. I have tried answers from the SO forum.

```
File ff = new File(".");

String pt = ff.getCanonicalPath()+"\\Selenium APIs";

String pt1 = ff.getCanonicalPath()+"\\Selenium APIs\\Start Selenium Server.bat";                

String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", pt1};`enter code here`

Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);    

p.waitFor();
```

when executed a cmd opens with the path name, but content of batch file is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (set timeout according to your requirements):

```
...
String[] command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c", pt1};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new InterruptScheduler(Thread.currentThread()), 60000);
try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    process.destroy();
    throw new TimeoutException("Command not terminated in 60 sec");
} finally {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: i have tried. see cmd window is opening with the file path. But nothing after that. I also tried with the processbuilder but nothing happens, not even cmd is opening.                                                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pt);
    //pb.directory(new File(ff.getCanonicalPath()+"\\Selenium APIs"));
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();